# Different MongoDB pooling behaviour between local machine and Amazon instance

Tags: java, macos, mongodb, amazon-web-services, ubuntu-12.04

I have a problem to understand why the same version of MongoDB (3.x) has a different behavior between my local machine (Mac OS X 10.11) and an Ubuntu 12.04 instance on Amazon.

Actually, I have a java application using MongoDB Async driver, and on my local machine the number of connections is growing every time I execute requests, whereas on Amazon the sockets are by default released after each execution, which makes the number of connections used stable.

Is there any internal MongoDB default parameter for pooling which could explain this behavior difference?

PS : I went to check that one difference is that I am using wiredtiger storage on my local machine whereas on Amazon I am using the old mmapv1. Could it be because of that ?

Answer (score 0):

The below info may be useful to you:

***Most MongoDB drivers support a parameter that sets the max number of connections (pool size) available to your application. The connection pool size can be thought of as the max number of concurrent requests that your driver can service. The default pool size varies from driver to driver, e.g. for Node it is 5, whereas for Python it is 100. If you anticipate your application receiving many concurrent or long-running requests, we recommend increasing your pool size- adjust accordingly!***

Source: [MongoDB Connection Pooling](http://blog.mongolab.com/2013/11/deep-dive-into-connection-pooling/)

Comment: The mongodb pool is configured the same both on my local machine and on Amazon : the min pool size is 0 and the max pool size is 100. So, I can understand the behavior on my local machine, the driver creating a lot of connections until 100, but why this number of connections is stable on Amazon exactly with the same tests played ?